# How can I find the arc length of some interval on this parametric object?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, arc-length, stereographic-projections, interval-arithmetic

I want to find the arclength some interval bounded by points $P$ and $Q$ on a parametric object. This parametric object is defined by the 2D stereographic function: $f(x, y) = (tx, 1 + t(y-1))$ . If you plug in all of the points of a centered-at-origin unit circle and for each point, transform its $t$ value from $1 \le t \le \frac{1}{1 - y}$ in a linear fashion, you'll get a nice transformation from the circle to the $y = 0$ line or the x-axis. If you look at this parametric object at the "half way" position, perhaps at $t = \frac{1}{2(1 - y)}$ for each point, you'll then understand what I tried to do with this drawing:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WhKE.jpg)

I think it would be useful to convert our function from multivariable to singlevariable. Therefore $f(\theta) = (tcos(\theta), 1 + t(sin(\theta) - 1))$

I think it would then be useful to get $t$ in terms of $\theta$. The best I can do is get $t$ in terms of $\theta$ and some other constant, call it $a$. The constant $a$ represents how far into the transformation you are. When $a = 0$, the circle is itself and when $a = 1$, the circle is fully transformed into the y=0 line. Therefore after following the linear $t = t_i + a(t_f - t_i)$ format and knowing that we want $1 \le t \le \frac{1}{1 - sin(\theta)}$ this gives us $t_i = 1$ and $t_f = \frac{1}{1 - sin(\theta)}$ Therefore $t = 1 + a(\frac{1}{1 - sin(\theta)} -  1)$

Therefore our original function where $t$ is now in terms of $\theta$ turns into: $f(\theta) = ((1 + a(\frac{1}{1 - sin(\theta)} -  1))cos(\theta), 1 + (1 + a(\frac{1}{1 - sin(\theta)} -  1))(sin(\theta) - 1))$

This then means that $f'(\theta)_x = \frac{a}{1 - sin(\theta)} + (a - 1)sin(\theta)$. and $f'(\theta)_y = (1 - a)cos(\theta)$

Following the format of $arclength = \int_{\theta i}^{\theta f}  \sqrt{(f'(\theta)_x)^2 + (f'(\theta)_y)^2}\, dθ $ is how I arrived at my answer so far:

$$arclength = \int_{\theta i}^{\theta f}  \sqrt{(\frac{a}{1 - sin(\theta)} + (a - 1)sin(\theta))^2 + ((1 - a)cos(\theta))^2}\, dθ $$

When a = 0, you're finding the arc length of a centered-at-origin unit circle. When a = 1, you're finding the "arclength" of the y = 0 line (which is just a linear distance). When a = anything in between, you're finding the arclength of a curvy line interval such as the one in the image attached to this post. The problem with this answer is that it is only integrable at $a = 0$, so circle segments are the only arc lengths that I can actually find

---

From here on out, I will attempt to interpret @SV-97's answer to see if it will help me get an integrable function at all values of a.

"Okay, if you express the way t changes as a function of θ you can consider this as a "curve on a manifold""

Alright so I do have t in terms of $\theta$ I got $t = 1 + a(\frac{1}{1 - sin(\theta)} -  1)$ and I explain where it came from above

I'm having a hard time understanding why you bumped things up to a higher dimensional manifold. I'll do more reading on geodesics of riemann manifolds

Comment: If your arc is defined by parametric equation $(x(t),y(t),z(t))$, then $dl=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}=\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2+z'(t)^2}dt$.

What is $f(x,y)$ in your question? If it is $z(x,y)$ it does not define arc, it does define surface. What is $t$ in your question?

Comment: I think it's correct but I don't know too much. but I think you could've just integrated with the tx and 1+t(y-1).

Comment: It seems like you want to have a curve such that you go from one point to the next by changing $\theta$ but $t$ also changes? Can you explain this relationship? To avoid an X-Y problem: given some "parametric object" as you called it - let's say a surface - and two points on this object you want to find the distance between those points when taking a route on this surface? So something similar to the length of a straight line connecting two points in euclidean space?

Comment: @SV-97 I think you have the general idea of it. As θ changes, so does t. Every point of the surface has it's own unique variable t. There is not a single variable t that governs the transformation from the circle to the line. Instead, every point has it's own t. "So something similar to the length of a straight line connecting two points in euclidean space?" - I think euclidean distance should be considered between neighbor points of the surface and then take the sum of all of these small euclidean distances between points P and Q to get the arclength distance between P and Q along the surface

Comment: @AdamS Okay, if you express the way t changes as a function of $\theta$ you can consider this as a "curve on a manifold". Basically you consider the Graph of $f$ where you also pull out $t$ as a variable, so the image of $\phi(x,y,t) = (x, y, t, tx, 1+t(y-1))$. You can consider this as basically a higher dimensional surface which we call *manifold*. Since it's a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ the surrounding space induces a so called "metric" on this manifold called the euclidean metric, so a way to measure lengths and distances (this makes it a riemannian manifold).

Comment: What you now want to consider is a curve on this manifold, which you can for example get by writing all the parameters of $\phi$ as functions of another parameter $\tau$ (your $\theta$ basically). Let's call this curve $$\gamma(\tau) := \phi(x(\tau), y(\tau), t(\tau))$$. Then the metric of this curve on the manifold is given by $\dot{\gamma}$ and by jacobi's transformation theorem you can compute the length of these curves by as $$\int_a^b \lVert \dot{\gamma}(\tau) \rVert_2 d\tau.$$ I think the thing you're after is to find the so called "geodesics" of the manifold:

Comment: basicaly the equivalent to straight lines in euclidean space. You can find these via an ordinary differential equation, the so called geodesic equation.

So your basic idea is correct, the $d$ expression you've given should turn out to be the metric of the curve (just expressed differently). But you have to consider how $t$ and $\theta$ change at once if you want to consider a curve like that.

Comment: It appears that this is a re-post of a [deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4262939/how-can-i-find-the-arclength-of-some-interval-on-this-parametric-object) by the same author.  Please don't repost questions, and, instead, work on the original post to make it clearer.

Comment: @MichaelBurr sorry about the delete and repost. I won't do that again in the future